# Correct way to use eclipse and xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I downloaded the pdt plugin for eclipse for php development. I have mamp installed , with the web port set at 80. The name of my project is PHPTest.

I have one file in it  ,called helloworld.php.
[image]

Hello world just echoes A text.

This project is located at
/Users/MYUSERNAME/EclipseProjects

When I run the project by right clicking on it, It shows this error in my browser :

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /PHPTest/helloworld.php was not found on this
> server.

So, why does this happen ? Is there some setting that I am missing?
or is the only way to get this running is to change the project's directory to the public html folder of mamp ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't related to xdebug support. Your HTTP server know nothing about your projects. you can fix this in three way:

1. Manually copy/paste project to your MAMP document root dir (default is  /Applications/MAMP/httpdocs)
2. Change MAMP document root dir to workspace: /Users/MYUSERNAME/EclipseProjects (easies way)
3. Move your workspace to document root dir (/Applications/MAMP/httpdocs)